# CSS: Relative positioning and scrolling inner elements

Tags: css, scroll, position

I'm looking for a way to scroll a panel that sits below a panel that doesn't scroll. Here's a fiddle with what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/zh59w/

Basically, the 'stay on top' needs to stay on top but all the 'scroll' elements needs to scroll as necessary. I was hoping by nesting the scrolling elements in a div (named nest), and position that nest relatively, then I'd be able to position the scrolling div absolutely, but when I do that it seems to take up no space and disappears.

The closest thing I can get to work is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zh59w/1/

But you'll see I have to cheat by setting the:

```
#scroll {
  top: 20px;
}
```

But I'd like to avoid this because I don't know how big the 'stay on top' is going to be.

Anything I can do (other than set the 'stay on top' to fixed)?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a fixed div that stays at the top of the page:

HTML:

```
<div id="stay_on_top">STAY ON TOP</div>
<p>SCROLL</p>
```

CSS:

```
#stay_on_top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aziom/ceNFH/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but if you see my note at the very bottom of the page, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use fixed either.  The reason is there will be content above this and I don't know where to "stick" the content as fixed.  Sorry I wasn't clear.